# Self-Contained Single-File Win Form app does not run

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-publishsinglefile

I am on VS 2019 16.8.3 with .Net 5.0.

I have created a simple Win Form project without any NuGet or project dependency.  I have made sure it runs out of the IDE.

When I published the project to a self-contained single file exe, it does not run.  The Task explorer briefly showed the exe and switch it to suspended before killing it.  **The exe works fine after I republished it either without the single-file or the self-contained option.  It seems like both options cannot co-exist.**

Any idea?

Comment: How did you publish it? `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true` should be just fine. Also, are there any errors in event log?

Comment: You may also set [`IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract`](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/single-file/design.md#optional-settings) setting to `true`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski...I use the Publishing option on the IDE (right click on the project and select Publish from the context menu).  That feature has the Configuration options for me to select.